# Python -> Get all valid media download url's from a webfolder

Tags: python, file, web-scraping, python-requests, download

I have a website here who has a link structure like this

```
https://example.com/assets/contents/1627347928.mp4
https://example.com/assets/contents/1627342345.mp4
https://example.com/assets/contents/1627215324.mp4
```

And I want to use python to get all links to download, when I access the folder /assets/contents/ i get a 404 error, so I can't see all the media to download from this web folder, but I know all the MP4 files has 10 CHARACTERS and all of them start with "1627******.mp4"
Can I do a LOOP to check all the links from that website and get all VALID links? Thanks!!!!!!!!!!!! I am newbie on python right now!

I could check if have media mp4/media with that code i can see the headers of a file, but how to make a loop to check all the links and download automatically? Or just show me the valid links? Thanks!!

```
import requests
link = 'https://example.com/assets/contents/1627347923.mp4'
r = requests.get(link, stream=True)
print(r.headers)
```

Comment: Where do you get the links from? an html page? Post concrete info about that please.

Comment: I don't have all the links here, and I can't post REAL links here because it's a private content, but the link structure its example.com/assets/contents/1627******.mp4, I want to do a loop on that 6 characters to 000000 to 999999 and get all the media! Understand now?

Comment: `names = [ 1627347923, 1627347924, 1627347925]` make a list, iterate it and build links as `'https://example.com/assets/contents/{}.mp4'.format(item)`

Answer (score 0):

yes you can run a loop, check the status code or if requests.get() throws an error you get back and as such get all the files, but there are some problems which might stop you from choosing that

1. Your files are in the format of "1627******.mp4", which means a for loop would check for 10^6 entries, if all the * are numbers, which is not efficient. If you are planning to include characters and special characters, it would be highly inefficient.
2. What if in the future you have more than 10^6 files? Your format will have to change and so your code will have to change.

A much more simple, straight forward and efficient solution would be to have a place to store your data, a file or better a database, where you can just query and get all your files. You can just run your query to get the necessary details.

Also, a 404 error means the page you are trying to reach is not found, in your case, it essentially means it doesn't exist.

A sample code a/c to check if link exists

```
files = []
links = ["https://www.youtube.com/","https://docs.python.org","https://qewrt.org"]

for i in links:
    try:
        requests.get(i) // If link doesnt exists, it throws an error, else the link is appended to the files list
        files.append(i)
    except:
        print(i+" doesnt exist")
print(files)
```

Building on this, based on your condition, checking for all files if they exist in the given format:

```
import requests

file_prefix = 'https://example.com/assets/contents/1627'

file_lists = []
for i in range(10**6):
    suffix = (6-len(str(i)))*"0"+str(i)+".mp4"
    file_name = file_prefix+suffix
    try:
        requests.get(file_name)
        file_lists.append(file_name)
    except:
        continue
for i in file_lists:
    print(i)
```

Comment: Shashanka, all the links has the 10 character format and all numbers, never letters or special characters, I just want to get all valid links printed on the cmd or a txt file...

Comment: I get that, I'm saying what if in the future, you have more files.

Comment: I have added a sample code to get your desired results, but beware it will take time due to the same explanation I gave before.

Answer (score 0):

Print if file exists or not

```
import requests
names = [ 1627347923, 1627347924, 1627347925]
base = 'https://example.com/assets/contents/{}.mp4'

for item in names:
    link = base.format(item)
    print(link)
    r = requests.head(link, allow_redirects=True)
    if r.status_code == 200:
        print("found {}.mp4".format(item))
        #open('{}.mp4'.format(item), 'wb').write(r.content)
    else:
        print("File no found or error getting headers")
```

Or try to download it

```
import requests
names = [ 1627347923, 1627347924, 1627347925]
base = 'https://example.com/assets/contents/{}.mp4'
for item in names:
    link = base.format(item)
    print(link)
    # uncomment below to download
    #r = requests.get(link, allow_redirects=True)
    #open('{}.mp4'.format(item), 'wb').write(r.content)
```

Comment: Nice, and If i want to populate the array with 0000000000 to 9999999999, what I do?

Comment: oops, that's 1 billion numbers. Not sure if you can or want to do that. It would mean 1 billion requests to that site

Comment: sorry, just 1626000000 to 1627999999

Comment: You have the numbers, google how to make a list out of that sequence. Jul 11 to Aug 3, btw.

Answer (score 0):

Based on all your codes and LMC codes, I do a thing who test all the MP4 files and show me the "headers", how I can only pick links who has a mp4 valid file like the link

```
import requests

file_prefix = 'https://example.com/assets/contents/1627'

file_lists = []
for i in range(10**6):
    suffix = (6-len(str(i)))*"0"+str(i)+".mp4"
    file_name = file_prefix+suffix
    try:
        requests.get(file_name)
        file_lists.append(file_name)
        r = requests.get(file_name, stream=True)
        print(file_name)        
        print(r.headers)
    except:
        continue
for i in file_lists:
    print(i)
```